# VB.NET Get Only Year from Date

Tags: vb.net, datetime, date, casting

I'm pulling into a variable a datetime value. Now, I want to post this value back to my database, but I need it to be only the year digits. How do I get VB.NET to trim the month, day, and time off and just return the four character year (e.g. 2011)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Date.Today.Year` is what you're looking for, or for an existing date, just `someDateVariable.Year`

Comment: I get the message: "Year is not a member of 'System.Linq.IQueryable(Of Date?)"

Comment: I figured it out, I needed to make it: getYear.First.Value.Year

Answer (score 4):

i know this is a bit late to answer
but, it wont hurt telling, try "year(now) " and load it to a variable
Example:

```
Dim Year_in_Digits = Year(Now)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim myDate As DateTime = #1/1/2011#
Dim myYear As Int32 = myDate.Year
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a property on the DateTime structure called 'Year'. This returns an integer representing just the year.

If you need to convert this to a string, just use the ToString() function.

So..

```
MyDT.Year.ToString()
```

That's a c# example, I'm sure VB.Net is going to be very similar.

Answer (score 2):

I just had to do this for my VB program.

```
 Dim Year As Integer    
 Year = Convert.ToInt32(Now.ToString("yyyy"))
```

Use just `"yy"` if you want two digit year. Then, when you need to display it somewhere:

```
year.tostring
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help because I tested it

```
Dim nowYear As Integer = Date.Now.Year
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late,but am sure i will help someone

To get exact year in **vb**:

`Dim date As String=Now.Year.ToString()`